# Who originally worked out the magnetic field produced by a solenoid and toroid?

Tags: physics, electromagnetism, mathematical-physics, magnetism

Although, it seems very easy to find the magnetic field produced by a solenoid or a toroid, all we got to do is to make a suitable an **Amperian Loop** and take the $\mathbf B$ out of the integral and so on.

But the main step is to find the direction of magnetic field. For example see these derivations of Griffiths:

[Toroid 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgt1b.png).

[Toroid 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjDUI.png)

I want to know who actually drived those equations, who actually worked out for the directions of magnetic field (Griffiths has done his)?

I searched for magnetic field by solenoid and toroid but found nothing historical. I aimed at finding something from Wikipedia’s “Refernces” or “External Links”. I read somewhere that Wilhelm Eduard Weber did work out the field for some geometrical shapes.

So, I request for some refernces where I can find the actual derivations of magnetic field produced by solenoid and toroid.

Comment: Hm?  At some point the community settled on a defined "direction,"  similar to defining the cartesian 3D coordinates via the "right-hand rule."   Are you looking for something more?

Comment: I found that it was Pierre De Laplace who actually worked out the magnetic fields not Mr. Biot or Mr. Savart. I found it Greiner’s book on EM.